# How to detect whether an UWP app is really active?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this little Autohotkey script which toggles Bluetooth just fine:

```
SendMode Input
Run, ms-settings:bluetooth
WinWaitActive, Settings
Sleep 300
Send,{Tab}{Space}
WinClose, A
```

but I am slightly bothered by the `Sleep 300` in there. It seems despite the `WinWaitActive` the app is not really active and I need to wait for it and I couldn't find anything better than a specified set of time. What would be better to wait for?

Answer (score 1):

```
SendMode Input
Run, ms-settings:bluetooth
WinWait, Settings  ; or:
/* 
WinWait, Settings,, 2 ; wait 2 seconds maximally until the specified window exists
if ErrorLevel ; if the command timed out
{
    MsgBox, WinWait timed out.
    return
}
*/
IfWinNotActive,  Settings, ,WinActivate, Settings
WinWaitActive, Settings  ; or:
/* 
WinWaitActive, Settings,, 2 ; wait 2 seconds maximally  until the specified window is active
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, WinWaitActive timed out.
    return
}
*/
; Sleep 300 ; needed in some programs that may not react immediately after activated
Send,{Tab}{Space}
WinClose, A
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm

Comment: This answer doesn't help me at all. Your answer includes "; Sleep 300 ; needed in some programs that may not react immediately after activated" which is exactly my problem! I don't want to wait 300 or 200 or 400 -- I want to wait until the program is ready to accept keystrokes. Surely the programs indicate they are ready to accept input by some way? Reading some event queue? Something?

Comment: If you don't get the error message "WinWaitActive timed out", this means that the window is really active after maximal 2 seconds (this was your question). Whether it will react immediately after activated depends on the program and the situation (too many factors to be considered). Therefore you are always on the right side, if you add a sleep before sending the commands, 300 ms isn't a long time.